# Sharepoint 2010 Client Object Model - Get the name of the current list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, client

I'm trying to create a simple custom action button for the Ribbon menu in Sharepoint 2010.

I want to keep it generic, so no hard coding of library names etc.

How can I find out the name of the current list being viewed? I would imagine that this is possible without having to parse it from the Url.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took a bit of digging, but I found the answer in the end. You can get the Id of the list in Javascript by using:

```
//Get the Id of the list
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that in the SPContext class

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.List;
string listTitle = list.Title;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.aspx

To parse the url you can use something like this

VB.NET

```
Private Function TryGetListName() As String
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ListName) Then
        Dim path() As String = Me.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Trim("/"c).Split("/"c)
        Dim listName As String = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To path.Length - 1
            If path(i).ToLower = "lists" Then
                If i < path.Length - 1 Then
                    listName = path(i + 1)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Return listName
    Else
        Return Me.ListName
    End If
End Function
```

C#

```
private string TryGetListName()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ListName)) {
        string[] path = this.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Trim('/').Split('/');
        string listName = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i <= path.Length - 1; i++) {
            if (path[i].ToLower() == "lists") {
                if (i < path.Length - 1) {
                    listName = path[i + 1];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return listName;
    } else {
        return this.ListName;
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to do this with Javascript. Really sorry for not stating that clearly in my original post!

Comment: Hmm the better way would be to have a codebehind page serving the javascript. If you want to do it with js do something with var url = window.location;
var urlparts = url.split('/');

Comment: I don't think this is possible. My custom action javascript is constructing a querystring for my application page and then opening it through the SP Modal dialogue. I don't think the application page code behind will be able to use SPContext to access the list name, because it's not on a list page? It also makes more sense to have the list name passed in with the querystring